# How to avoid aiding academic misconduct when tutoring online

Tags: teaching, tutoring

I have started teaching online recently. Sometimes I am asked not only to teach, but also to actively help in a particular project. If it was a paper, I would ask be included in the list of authors, or at least acknowledged.

How should I approach this issue if the material which is produced is a Masters' thesis for example? I have no concern about teaching some material which can be used by students to advance their thesis, but advising them on how to write the thesis itself seems different.

Is it ok if I ask them to write an acknowledgement where they specify that I have made some contributions to the work, or this situation cannot be saved such a way? I am hoping to be able to be involved ethically in such a project because it helps with my finances but I have ethical boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to ask the client if they are comfortable with you asking their advisor for guidance, which of course makes your participation visible. If they won't do that, then I'd guess that they want to use you improperly.

But, if they are willing to keep the advisor in the loop then it also allows for each case to be handled individually and in the open. One size may not fit all here.

If they won't do this, then you might consider either dropping them or, alternatively, sticking close to what is more obviously acceptable.